# IBM Bluemix, JavaBuildpack, Deployment issue

Tags: tomcat, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I have developed an app that runs on Tomcat and trying to push the app on IBM Bluemix using the java_buildpack but the app is not starting.

The reason as I can see in log is : "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"

The JDBC driver for DB2 needs to be in the lib folder of Tomcat.

As this is the first time I am deploying at Bluemix using JAVABUILDPack, I really don't know how to push the DB2 Jar to the Tomcat/lib folder on Bluemix.

Please help.

Below is the Log :-

```html
Catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] SEVERE  Exce
ption opening database connection
2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:644)
2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.startInternal(JDBCRealm.java:717)

2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
2015-09-06T18:43:41.99+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your app have to run against the java buildpack?  Can you try running against the default buildpack in Bluemix, which is the WebSphere Liberty Buildpack.

```
cf push <appname>
```

Comment: I cannot use the Websphere Liberty Buildpack because my application uses Tomcat Realm. I also tried initially but half of the functionalities of my application are not working.

Comment: You may be able to fork the java buildpack, then place the DB2 jars under https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/tree/master/resources/tomcat

Comment: the JDBC error is now solved after following the way you said ... Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out. Accept answer so this one starts to bubble to the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [DB2 driver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) JAR to the *WEB-INF/lib* directory for your web application. This will be automatically loaded by Tomcat during deployment.

> /WEB-INF/lib/ - This directory contains JAR files that contain Java class files (and associated resources) required for your application, such as third party class libraries or JDBC drivers.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Shared_Library_Files

Comment: Yes the DB2 Jar files are already there in the WEB-INF/lib. 

when I run the same application on my local server also then I have to add the JAR in the run configuration else the application throwing the same error.

Comment: As this project is for my University and I cannot share the code publicly, can you please help me via skype. I will share my teamviewer over there and you can help me.

My skype id is :- suneetaks

I am online on skype

Comment: I'll try to find a sample project you can try out that should work

Comment: On the local host also if I add the JDBC jars in the run configuration then it is working fine. And If i remove them from the run configuration then it is throwing the error. The jars are always there in WEB-INF/lib. When I am exporting the project as war then the local tomcat run configurations are not applied on the bluemix. Please help.

Comment: Please check that the WAR file you are pushing to Bluemix contains the JDBC Driver jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory within your WAR file.